# How do I Upload My PHP folder to the Internet?

Tags: php, url, server, upload, uploading

I have my PHP File I want to Upload the File to the Internet and It is runned properly. I have XAMMP install and when I upload it to the Internet it looks like how it looks like in the XAMMP preview.

What I mean is I want to upload my PHP Folder to the Web for it's Internet Address to look like:
https://www.myfolder.com/index.php

Please help me.

Comment: are you asking how to host your web service on the internet?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you mean but my guess is you have a folder/application want to upload that. Usually that would be done through an FTP client

Comment: This question will probably get closed. But here is an attempt to answer your question. Find a website hosting provider. Point your domain to their server per their instructions. Setup FTP per their instructions and upload. There is much more involved so your best bet is to reach out to whomever you plan on hosting the website.

Comment: @crock I want to host my webservice on the internet like a .php file like this URL for Example: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/time/hours.php